# can not resolve any of dependency import

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

**#StrangeError** This issue persists when I changed my system. I opened a project in a new laptop.
Now I can run an app, Gradle build is successful but all dependency imports show not resolved like the screenshot.

[image]

**Note that all dependencies are added in-app level `build.gradle` and project is running perfectly.**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.kpis.servertracker"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
def SUPPORT_LIB_VER = '27.0.2'
def BUTTER_KNIFE_VER = '8.8.1'
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':Baselib')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIB_VER"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${SUPPORT_LIB_VER}"
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${BUTTER_KNIFE_VER}"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${BUTTER_KNIFE_VER}"
}
```

**Gradle build is successful, it does not show any error.**

I have tried

- Clean, rebuild
- Restarted AS with invalidate cache
- Delete build folder inside app
- Delete .gradle folder

Comment: delete .gradle folder and try .

Comment: which .gradle , project .gradle or users folder .gradle?

Comment: Post your gradle file or update your compileSdkVersion to 27 and use implementation instead of compile to add dependencies.

Comment: ".gradle" inside project

Comment: Tried delete .gradle, not worked

Comment: If possible please try to build using support version `27.1.0` or `26.1.0`

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Does not work

Comment: @Khemraj Try to **Synchronize Gradle libraries**, it's very simple, just open the tab Gradle on the right side, and click on the root row in the list and after that -> click on Synchronize button (the blue spinning arrow)

Comment: did your project depends on another module which is include `implementation` with RecyclerView?

Comment: @jantursky Synchronize Gradle libraries does not work

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך no it does not

Comment: @Khemraj Post the whole gradle file. It will help us.

Comment: @jantursky posted app level build.gradle

Comment: `implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${BUTTER_KNIFE_VER}"` should be `annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${BUTTER_KNIFE_VER}"`

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך Does not work.

Answer (score 1):

That sometimes happen in your project.

So you need to Delete your **.Gradle folder** in your project directory.

**Projectdirectory->.gradle folder Delete it** And

Then open Android Studio and build project

Thanks!